# Least-squares digital IIR filter design (with arbitrary responses)

Tags: matlab, filter-design, frequency-response, infinite-impulse-response

I'm studying the IIR filter design that is described in the book: [Algorithms for the constrained design of digital filters with arbitrary phase and magnitude responses](http://www.nt.tuwien.ac.at/fileadmin/users/gerhard/diss_Lang.pdf).

You can get the code at page 171 (at least the main function), and here is an example of a filter design :

```
M=4;
N=4;
tau=5;
om=pi*[linspace(0,0.2,20),linspace(0.4,1,60)];
D=[exp(-1i*om(1:20)*tau),zeros(1,60)];
W=ones(1,80);
[b,a,e]=mpiir_l2(M,N,om,D,W,0.98);
```

This is the design of a pass-band linear phase lowpass filter

[image]

There is something I don't understand in this code: `exp(-1i*om(1:20)*tau)` is a way to create regularly spaced points with constant phase change and magnitude = 1. But I don't understand the parameter `tau`. I tried to change that parameter and I had totally different results: like a notch instead of a lowpass.

- How do you choose that number ?
- I have to design my filters according to the user desire but how to guess that parameter?
- And also how to you choose the phase angles shift ?

Jeff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `tau` was chosen so that the phase of `D` at $om = 0.2$ is $-\pi$.

It is easier to understanding what is going on if you plot `D`, which is the desired magnitude/phase response of the filter. Add the following code to help you visualize what is going on:

```
figure(1);
subplot(2,1,1);
  plot(om/pi,10*log10(abs(D)+realmin));
  title('Magnitude Response');
  xlabel('Frequency (normalized)');
  ylabel('Magnitude (dB)');
  axis([0, 1, -80, 10]);
subplot(2,1,2);
  plot(om/pi,angle(D)*180/pi);
  title('Phase Response');
  xlabel('Frequency (normalized)');
  ylabel('Phase (degrees)');
  axis([0, 1, -180, 180]);
```

When you look at the resulting plot, you can see that the current value of tau gives a phase response which dips down to $-180^\circ$ at the cutoff frequency.  Notice that the phase will wrap back around from $-180^\circ$ to $180^\circ$.  This will almost always lead to undesired results in a system.

Answer (score 3):

Well, let's decode it:

```
om=pi*[linspace(0,0.2,20),linspace(0.4,1,60)];
```

`om` is a variable that ranges from 0 to pi with two different spacings (one from `0` to `0.2*pi` and one from `0.4*pi` to `pi`.

Then, to find `D` (the desired response), we do:

```
-1i*om(1:20)*tau
```

This takes the first twenty entries in `om` and multiplies them by `tau` and `-i1` = $-\sqrt{-1}$.

That makes the frequency range (`D` in the above) from `0` to `0.2*pi*tau` (i.e. `pi` since `tau` is `5`).

Checking page 171, we see:

```
om frequency grid 0<=om<= pi
D complex desired frequency response on the grid om
```

which means that `om` has to be between 0 and `pi`, and `D` is the desired response.

If you've changed `tau`, causing `D` to have a greater phase (more delay).

What I suspect is happening is that the phase (and, therefore, the delay) you've changed it to cannot easily be approximated by a $4^{\rm th}$ order filter (`N` or `M` in your script).

Comment: Changing the value of `tau` *does not* actually affect the value of `om`.